# Unable to insert data in MySQL, if it contains " or '

Tags: mysql

I am using this code  to insert data into MySQL

```
<textarea name='description' class='description' placeholder='Enter Description'></textarea>
```

It works fine, but if the Text contains any `'` then, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's friends learn they're about to be downsized' at line 2
```

However, If i Insert the data directly by opening PHPMyAdmin, it works fine. How to fix it?

Comment: You have to escape those characters with `\'` or  `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Prepared statements are your friend. You'll never have to worry about those pesky quoting issues again. And it's more secure than using real_escape_string.

Comment: I will try Prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the character before inserting into DB like so `\'`.

Comment: You mean, this is what i Type: 

"John/'s car is so beautiful"??

Comment: It will be John\'s car is so beautiful.

Comment: Note that you don't have to do this by hand, just pass your post data to mysqli_real_escape_string() and that will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Strings defined by `'` in mysql and mariadb, so if a quote exist in string, escape it with backslash like `\'`.

Comment: You mean, this is what i Type: "John/'s car is so beautiful"??

Comment: You must be send "John\'s car is so beautiful" to mariadb. Can add your php code to the question to better answering?

Answer (score 0):

use  `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. it Escape special characters in a string. in your case "'" is special character.